# What are the ways to get payment from users for paid applications?

Tags: appexchange, app

I want to publish my application for paid. what are ways to get payment from  the user if they install my application ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppExchange Checkout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_checkout_overview.htm), powered by Stripe, or you can choose your own Merchant Account service, such as PayPal or Authorize.net.

There are a few caveats for using Checkout, though:

> The fee to use AppExchange Checkout is 15% plus 30 cents per successful transaction. We don’t charge setup fees, monthly service charges, or card storage fees. There’s also no minimum revenue share.
>
> You can’t accept payments from every country yet. For a list of supported countries, visit https://stripe.com/global. If your country isn’t listed, sign up to be notified when Stripe is available there.
>
> You must distribute your offering as a managed package.
>
> You can’t use AppExchange Checkout with OEM apps.

As long as you don't mind the fees and limitations, this is a rather convenient scenario for you and your clients, since it is integrated with salesforce.com already. You're also free to browse the AppExchange to find another third-party vendor if you choose.

Comment: I am using AppExchange checkout for payment option but I want to publish my app for 15 days trial, how it will work ?

Comment: @AJAYPRAKASHDUBEY The system manages the LMA licenses for you. The [FAQ](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/resource/1237050882000/help/Content/appexchange_checkout_faq.htm) explains a bit more.